# How to close the session when receive time too long?

Tags: python, starlette

I used `starlette framework`
I write a route in below:

```py
@app.websocket_route("/wss_back", name="run_in_backend")
async def wss_back(session: WebSocket):
    await session.accept()
    data = await session.receive_json()
    await run_code_in_subprocess(session)
    await session.send_json({"msgType": 1, "data": "good"})
    await session.close(1000)
```

But I can't make sure client session will send message to the wss server.

So, I want to set a time for receive timeout ? How can I achieve this?

If `await websocket.receive_json()` than 5s, close the session.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for

```
await asyncio.wait_for(session.receive_json(), timeout=5)
```